# balloonstyle for clickable thumbnail

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have a style defined as:

```
<Style id="style1"> 
<BalloonStyle><text>$[description]</text></BalloonStyle> 
<IconStyle><Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle-lv.png</href></Icon></IconStyle> 
</Style>
```

and placemark description as:

```
<description><![CDATA[ 
          <table width="400"><tr>
             <td><a href="img/test.png">Open Image<br><img src="img/test.png" width=200 /></a></td> 
             <td>Some Text Goes Here</td>
          </tr></table> 
]]></description>
```

Is it possible to make it so that when they click on the image it opens up in the default viewer or in another browser page?  Right Click (open in new window, open image, open) doesn't seem to do anything.  The images are in the KMZ file.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Peter - I just duplicated your setup and I saw the same behavior.

After doing some tests, it appears the web browser is only accessed when your link references something on the Internet, not local files (like your `img/test.png`).  Additionally, you need to include the `http://` at the beginning of the URL.

I tried using `<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>` and it didn't work.  Once I changed the link to `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`, then it worked.

So my conclusion is that you need to host your images on a web server somewhere and reference them with a full URL for Google Earth to automatically open the web browser.